# How to remove seconds from TimeSpan?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Beginner in xamarin. Im tring to display the time as HH:mm without the seconds being added in. It appears on my form as example 12:30:00, i want just as 12:30. Do i need to change Date time function maybe, the code is currently working but displaying the time as hour minute seconds still.

The code also should allow the soonest time to appear at the top but it doesnt seem to be doing that either.

```
    void FindNextDue(ObservableCollection<UserMedDosagePayLoad> medtimes)
    {
        UserMedTimesFilteredList.Clear();

        int nowHour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
        int nowMinutes = DateTime.Now.Minute;
        TimeSpan now = new TimeSpan(nowHour, nowMinutes, 0);

        foreach (UserMedDosagePayLoad item in medtimes)
        {
            item.Nextduemessage = item.Dosage + " " + item.Dosageunit + 
                "due at " + item.Time;

            string[] DT = item.Time.Split(':');

            if (DT[0] != null)
            {
                int hr = Convert.ToInt32(DT[0]);
                int minutes = Convert.ToInt32(DT[1]);
                TimeSpan medTime = new TimeSpan(hr, minutes, 0);
                TimeSpan comparison = now.Subtract(medTime).Negate();

                TimeSpan TwentyFourHour = new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0);

                if (comparison.TotalMilliseconds <0)
                {
                    comparison = TwentyFourHour.Add(comparison);
                }

                TimeComparison.Add(comparison);                    
            }
        }

        //Order the collection of times so the next due is always first
        TimeComparison = new List<TimeSpan>(TimeComparison.OrderBy(h => h.Hours)
            .ThenBy(m => m.Minutes));

        List<string> UserMedIDs = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < TimeComparison.Count(); i++)
        {
            DateTime NextDue = DateTime.Now.Add(TimeComparison[i]);
            DateTime NextDueToCompare = new DateTime(NextDue.Year, NextDue.Month, 
                NextDue.Day, NextDue.Hour, NextDue.Minute, 0);

            string NextDueComparisonString = NextDueToCompare.ToString("HH:mm:ss");

            foreach (UserMedDosagePayLoad item in UserMedTimes)
            {
                if (item.Time == NextDueComparisonString && 
                    !UserMedIDs.Contains(item.Usermedid))
                {
                    UserMedTimesFilteredList.Add(item);
                    UserMedIDs.Add(item.Usermedid);
                }
            }

            UserMedTimes = medtimes;
            MedicationList.ItemsSource = UserMedTimesFilteredList;
            BusyIndicator.IsRunning = false;                            
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's a lot of code for a question asking how to format a `TimeSpan` string...please simplify to just the relevant part.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want hours and minutes to display, then remove "ss" from your format string

```
string NextDueComparisonString = NextDueToCompare.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

here, you are not specifying any format so it is using the default

```
item.Nextduemessage = item.Dosage + " " + item.Dosageunit + 
            "due at " + item.Time;
```

specify a format like this

```
item.Nextduemessage = item.Dosage + " " + item.Dosageunit + 
            "due at " + item.Time.ToString("HH:mm");
```

Comment: `HH` should be `hh` and the `:` need to be escaped with `\\ `...

Comment: @RufusL It should be HH as you want a 24 hour comparison. (and do you don't have to escape the colons)

Comment: Oh, sorry! I thought this was for a `TimeSpan`...my bad. I made a minor edit to your answer so I could change my vote. :)

Comment: @Jason I tried removed the ss but it still displays with the seconds as always 00

Comment: Is this the time displayed in the item.nextDueMessage?

Comment: Yes, I’ve tried displaying it just using the item.time field but still has same issue

Comment: see my last edit

Comment: No joy, get an error saying "string string.ToString() , Returns the instance of string; no actual conversion is performed. No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 argument."

Comment: Is item.Time a TimeSpan or a string?

Comment: It is a string calling the time into Nextduemessage

Comment: you need to apply the format string to the TimeSpan/DateTime object when you initially SET the value of item.Time

Comment: Would it be here?    
        /// <summary>
        /// ID getter/setter
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "time")]
        public string Time
        {
            get { return time; }
            set { time = value; }
        }

Comment: no, because that is just a string too.  Somewhere in your code you are assigning a value to that property, I can't tell you where that is.  The important thing to understand is that when you convert from a TimeSpan/DateTime object to a string, that is the point at which you need to apply the format.

Answer (score 1):

Use formatting if you don't want to see the seconds at all (12:48 for example).

The method gets a TimeSpan obj, and returns the time as a string without the seconds.

Read here to explore more about formatting.

### The custom function

```
public string GetTimeSpanWithoutSeconds(TimeSpan input)
{
    return input.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
}
```

### The "hh" custom format specifier

Represents the hour as a number from 01 through 12; that is, the hour is represented by a 12-hour clock that counts the whole hours since midnight or noon. A particular hour after midnight is indistinguishable from the same hour after noon. The hour is not rounded, and a single-digit hour is formatted with a leading zero. For example, given a time of 5:43 in the morning or afternoon, this format specifier displays "05".

### The "mm" custom format specifier

Represents the minute as a number from 00 through 59. The minute represents whole minutes that have passed since the last hour. A single-digit minute is formatted with a leading zero.